# Update table in Dexie

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I try to update a field named "Type" in indexedDB with Dexie

```
    var db = new Dexie("Commande");

    db.version(1).stores({
    commande: "++id,idClient,nomClient,idInterne,statut,Type"
    }); 

    db.commande.where("id").equals(getId).modify({Type: "Multi"});
```

I try this also :

```
db.commande.where("id").equals(getId).modify(function(value) {
this.value = new commande({Type: "Multi"});
});
```

And also that :

```
db.commande.update(getId, {Type: "Multi"});
```

My field "Type" is never updated :(

Someone can help me about that ?

[image: Image Table details]

Comment: Ok it is my fault.

Comment: This work like a charm, sorry. dbc.commande.where("id").equals(getId).modify({Type: "Multi"});

Comment: Did you ever figure out why db.table.update(id, changes) didn't work in your case? I am seeing the same now.

Comment: For future Google travelers, I ended up using .put (its semantics were safe to use in my case), but I still have no idea why .update didn't work.